# getting undefined error when i use populate in mongoose node js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
    Hi all am getting undefined when want to use populate .with jobid which is unique in both collections.please anyone let me know what is the issue

    crewbiesJobsSchema.virtual('jobs', {
                ref: 'Jobs',
                localField: 'jobId', 
                foreignField: 'jobId',
                justOne: false,
            });
            CrewbiesJobs.find({}).populate('jobs').exec(function(error, CJobs) {
                console.log(CJobs,'jobs s')
            });

when i console am getting cJobs undefined .when i console am getting cJobs undefined .

** Crewbies Model**

let crewbiesJobsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    jobTitle: String,
    jobId: {type: Schema.Types.String, unique: true ,ref:'Jobs'},
    startDate: String,
    endDate: String,
    country: String
}, {timestamps: true, toJSON: { virtuals: true } });

**Jobs Model**

let jobsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    jobTitle: String,
    jobId: {type: Schema.Types.String, unique: true ,ref:'CrewbiesJobs'},
    jobDescription: String,
    postedDate: String,
    filter1: [
        {
            label: String,
            value: String
        }
    ],
    filter2: [
        {
            label: String,
            value: String
        }
    ],
    filter3: [
        {
            label: String,
            value: String
        }
    ]
}, {timestamps: true});
```

Hi all am getting undefined when want to use populate .with jobid which is unique in both collections.please anyone let me know what is the issue   Hi all am getting undefined when want to use populate .with jobid which is unique in both collections.please anyone let me know what is the issue

Comment: can we see your models please

Comment: Can you also provide the lines, `mongoose.model("...", schema);`

Comment: `let CrewbiesJobs = mongoose.model('crewbies_jobs', crewbiesJobsSchema);            let Jobs = mongoose.model('flash_jobs', jobsSchema);`

Answer (score 0):

Your ref is the reference to the name you supplied when you called `mongoose.model(MODEL_NAME, schema)` Here for your `jobsSchema` you told mongoose that this schema is called `flash_jobs` you need to reference this when you supply your ref in the virtual.

```
crewbiesJobsSchema.virtual("jobs", {
    ref: "flash_jobs", // MODEL_NAME
    localField: "jobId",
    foreignField: "jobId",
    justOne: false
});
```

Comment: am getting response like this when i get   `{ _id: 5da93320c5821b4af85add8f,
    jobId: '1542',
    jobTitle: 'QA',
    startDate: '2019-08-16',
    endDate: '2019-12-01',
    country: 'China',
    createdAt: 2019-10-18T03:36:00.423Z,
    updatedAt: 2019-10-18T03:36:00.423Z,
    __v: 0,
    jobs: [] } ] 'jobs here' `     am getting data of crewbies jobs only am not getting match data with other flashjobs collection

Comment: @SairamGouni try chaning`jobId: Schema.Types.String` to `jobId: Schema.Types.ObjectId` and remove the refs in the schema